# A good to do / task app

Tags: macos, mac, widgets

I am looking for a good to do / tasking app or widget.  Basically I just want a list of items which I can check off when I have finished them - similar to Google Mail Tasks.

Comment: Subjective and argumentative. Bring real criteria.

Comment: iCal already offers what you want (`View`, `Show To Do List`). If you're not satisfied with it, tell us why. Otherwise this will just be another list of programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following web page might have what your looking for. The following quote and link are the page the quote was found and the top to-do-list manager.

http://techtites.com/2009/01/22/top-5-to-do-list-managers-for-mac-os-x/

> EtreTask
>
> EtreTask is a small, fast, easy-to-use
>   to-do list manager. It is designed not
>   to get in your way. It will never have
>   as many â€œfeaturesâ€ as its
>   competitors, but we feel that is a
>   good thing.

-Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

[Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/about/download/mac.php) has a Mac client that you might be interested in. Although it contains many features for general note-taking, it also has great support for making to-do lists...

> Remember the things you were supposed
>   to remember. Create to-do lists, jot
>   down random thoughts, leave a voice
>   memo, and more.